# twitter search engine system to filter hashtag or @

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i want to ask about twitter search engine, i want it for my web, for example

```
$data; //it's from search engine form
```

i want if `$data` beginning with `#` then i use mysql query for searching data that contain hashtag

and if `$data` beginning with `@`  then use mysql query for searching data that contain `@`

i want `$data` has been filtered before query

```
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT*FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%$data%'");
```

how to check data if it has `hashtag` or `@`? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
switch (substr($data,0,1)){
    case '@': //if $data begins with @
        mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%$data%'");
    break;
    case '#': //if $data begins with #
        mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE '%$data%'");
    break;
    default: //neither of above
        echo "your query doesn't begin with @ or #";   
}
```

Edit for comment below :

You are looking for `preg_match_all()` here is an example for what you want to do :

This will create 2 `arrays` (`$hashes`, and `$arobases`) containing the strings you want.

```
preg_match_all("(#[^\s]+)", "hello : #hash1 #hash2 @at1 @at2", $hashes);
preg_match_all("(@[^\s]+)", "hello : #hash1 #hash2 @at1 @at2", $arobases);
var_dump($hashes[0]);
echo "<br/><hr/>";
var_dump($arobases[0]);
```

Comment: if $data like "hey this is some #hashtag data, " how to substring it

Comment: I've edited my answer, sorry I didn't understood correctly the first time.